# Redhawk SDRROOT, don't see components

Tags: redhawksdr

Our admin installed stuff to `SDRROOT=/var/redhawk/sdr` but I wanted to have my own `SDRROOT`, which I set to `~/redhawk/sdr`.

The problem is that the I don't see components like sigGen, hardLimit in the components palette.
I followed the following instruction given by Axios.
These instructions did not solve my problem:

```
$ mkdir -p $SDRROOT/{dom/components,dom/waveforms,dom/domain,dev/devices,dev/nodes}

$ ln -s /var/redhawk/sdr/dom/mgr $SDRROOT/dom/mgr

$ ln -s /var/redhawk/sdr/dev/mgr $SDRROOT/dev/mgr

$ cp /var/redhawk/sdr/dom/domain/DomainManager.dmd.xml.template \
     $SDRROOT/dom/domain/DomainManager.dmd.xml

$ gedit $SDRROOT/dom/domain/DomainManager.dmd.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SDRROOT stands on its own. If you use your own, you need to ensure it contains any software you want to use. You haven't mentioned copying/linking the components you wanted to use into your SDRROOT (SigGen, etc). They should be inside /var/redhawk/sdr/dom/components. You could do this, for example, with:

```
cd ~/redhawk/sdr/dom/components
for $component in /var/redhawk/sdr/dom/components/*; do
  ln -s $component
done
```

Also, don't forget to update environment variables to point at your SDRROOT. Check the variables that get set in /etc/profile.d/redhawk.sh for reference.

Comment: Thanks very much.  Copying from /var/redhawk/sdr/* to my ~/redhawk/sdr/ should also work, correct?

Comment: Yes you can copy from the system's SDRROOT, BUT you when you upgrade REDHAWK to a newer version, you SHOULD do the copy again into your home directory otherwise you may get all sort of issues (such as failing to launch your Domain Manager and/or Device Manager, etc.)